# Android hashmap button id

Tags: java, android, hashmap

I´m making a list of items and 2 buttons for each item.
Ex:
Item1                On          Off
Item2                On          Off

I'm using a hashmap and i have an xml-file with a textview and two buttons.
My problem is that when i click a button i want to know which item it belongs to. I don't know how many items i will have so i reuse the same buttons so i want to set an id for each row.

My xml-file looks like this.

```
 <TextView android:id="@+id/DEVICE_CELL"
     android:layout_width="180dip"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

```
<Button android:id="@+id/OFF_BUTTON"
android:layout_width="60dip"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:onClick="turnOff"/>
```

And this is my hashmap and so on.

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("device", name);
            map.put("on", "ON");
            map.put("off", "OFF");


            mylist.add(map);
    SimpleAdapter dev = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist, R.layout.list_item,
                    new String[] {"device", "on", "off"}, new int[] {R.id.DEVICE_CELL, R.id.ON_BUTTON, R.id.OFF_BUTTON});
        list.setAdapter(dev);
```

Answer (score 0):

Every `View` in Android lets you set a "Tag".  The tag is just a Java Object, so you could set the item at the tag on the two buttons so you can retrieve it in the `OnClickListener`.

Comment: Stupid question maybe, but i'm not sure how to since i don't "make a button" with Button button=new Button.. Do i do that when i map it or in the xml-file?

Comment: You can do Button myButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.?????);  myButton.setTag(????);

Comment: HashMap only accepts String because you tell it to with `new HashMap<String, String>`.  Do you really need an ArrayList of HashMaps?  Or do you just want a list of something like pairs?

Comment: Then instead of using a HashMap you could make a simple class that just holds the button and whatever else you need and put that in the list